# Openshift garbage collection checks space on wrong parition

Tags: openshift, openshift-enterprise

Openshift Garbage Collection wasn't running so I was adjusting settings and found out that it is checking the wrong partition for used space.

```
[ImageManager]: Disk usage on "/dev/mapper/rhel_openshift--slave-root" (/) is at 35% which is over the high threshold (35%). Trying to free 1469043508 bytes
```

But docker is using /dev/mapper/docker--vg-docker--pool.

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/docker-storage
DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS=--storage-driver devicemapper --storage-opt dm.fs=xfs --storage-opt dm.thinpooldev=/dev/mapper/docker--vg-docker--pool --storage-opt dm.use_deferred_removal=true
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What version of OSE are you running? There was a bug identified here which seems related: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1300570

Which should be fixed in versions v3.1.1.904 onwards.

If you are running a newer version, please advise as I'm sure this is something that would affect many installations.

Comment: I was running 3.1 and recently upgraded to 3.2 which fixed the issue.